# How to receive data from pusher in react JS using laravel 5.8?

Tags: reactjs, pusher, laravel-5.8

I am using React JS on client side, Laravel on server side and pusher for notification, i am recieiving 
message on pusher and on client side as well on local environment but can't authenticate on server its working fine on local.
on server generating error as

> Pusher : Error :
>   {"type":"WebSocketError","error":{"type":"PusherError","data":{"code":null,"message":"Auth
>   value for subscription to private-notification is invalid: should be
>   of format 'key:signature'"}}}

React Code

```
import Pusher from "pusher-js";

Pusher.logToConsole = true;

var pusher = new Pusher('key', {
  cluster: 'ap2',
  forceTLS: true,
  authEndpoint: 'http://localhost:8000/api/pusher/auth',
  // authEndpoint: 'http://localhost:8000/api/broadcasting', 
  auth: {
    headers: authHeader()
  }
});

var channel = pusher.subscribe('private-testNotification');
channel.bind('OrderCreate', function(data) {
  // console.log('data', data);
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

Laravel Code

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function () {
    Route::post('pusher/auth', 'imagesController@pusherAuth');
});


public function pusherAuth(Request $request)
{
    \Debugbar::disable();
    $user = auth()->user();

    if ($user) {
        $pusher = new \Pusher(config('broadcasting.connections.pusher.key'), config('broadcasting.connections.pusher.secret'), config('broadcasting.connections.pusher.app_id'));
        echo $pusher->socket_auth($_POST['channel_name'], $_POST['socket_id']);
        return;
    }else {
        header('', true, 403);
        echo "Forbidden";
        return;
    }
}
```

Please suggest where i am wrong, Thanks in advance.